# How to annotate java package and reflect metadata

Tags: java, java-annotations

I would like to annotite java package using simple annotation:

```java
@Target(ElementType.PACKAGE)
public @interface Related {
    int apiVersion() default 0;
}
```

However when I try to add it to any package I've got compilation error

```
Error:(1, 14) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Related
  location: package com.test.xxx
```

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT**

After searching a bit I found also this kind of error

```
Error:(1, 1) java: package annotations should be in file package-info.java
```

Comment: Is there only one error produced by comiler?

Comment: thank you for quick answer! no, I found another one - `Error:(1, 1) java: package annotations should be in file package-info.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to place annotation on package you should create `package-info.java` file which should contain package definition like this:

```java
@Related
package tld.some.name;
```

To be able to reflect reflect package you also need to set up [`RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html)

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PACKAGE)
public @interface Related {
    // stuff...
}
```

And then you can finally reflect package:

```
SomeClassInPackage.class.getPackage().getAnnotation(Related.class)
```

You can also reflect package by name using [`java.lang.Package`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html)

```
Package.getPackage("tld.some.name").getAnnotation(Related.class)
```

Comment: But how can I reflect package based on string package name?